# notation for the external set of all positive unlimited real numbers

Tags: symbols

I couldn't find the notation for the external set of all positive unlimited real numbers. 
It's like the symbol of infinity with a slash over it 
I've tried \ninfty in fashion of \nequal  but it didn't work 
you can find this notation in this book [Nonstandard Analysis in Practice](https://books.google.dz/books?id=a5spdc-gKqUC&pg=PA146&lpg=PA146&dq=the%20external%20set%20of%20all%20positive%20unlimited%20real%20numbers&source=bl&ots=q4G8TFi-L1&sig=T0_rGSWxJ6cLBpqMm_Lh1VGfAUA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj1g6-7xYbfAhVMShUIHSkXD1sQ6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20external%20set%20of%20all%20positive%20unlimited%20real%20numbers&f=false)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine} 

\begin{document}

$\stackMath\stackinset{c}{0pt}{c}{0pt}{/}{\infty}$

\end{document}
```

[image]